# how can I show the images with curl method?

Tags: php, curl

I have 2 questions:

1) When I use the curl, my pictures not shown, why?

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.google.com'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

2) In destination page I have a text field, how can I fill it with curl method?

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually looking at google or some other server? It's possible that the response is catered to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that:

1. the images are used relatively, so the paths are incorrect if you use curl.
2. you should use the result of curl_exec and use that info to write into your textarea.

To get the result from the curl_exec method, set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option, like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Now you can get the value like so:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

It's all in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) by the way.

To get the images working you might want to do some regular expression replace where you look for anything within the src="" attribute and prefix that with, let's say http://www.google.com  (or whatever might be correct).

Comment: any idea,for photos? and for curl_exec could you please give me an example ? thnx

Comment: thanks a lot, how can I set a value on text filed? as your way I think we can get the value of text field, yes?

Comment: @MikeRedford: don't know what you mean by get the value of text field but either way you can a. use the result variable to push the value of that variable (from google.com) into a textfield or b. use the value of that variable to retrieve some data from a textfield on that page. Good luck!